# Converting measurements in python. Code errors. Stuck

Tags: python

Im working on an exercise that needs me to write a program that prompts the user for a measurement in meters and then converts it to miles, feet and inches.

Im stuck on converting the measurement to feet and inches. If you run the code and enter 3000. You get 9000 which is not the correct answer. What am I missing? Or am I just doing the math wrong.

```
feet_in_meter = 3.2804
meters_in_mile = 1609.34
inches_in_meter = 39.3701

meters = float(input("Please enter a measurement in meters: "))

print("Converted to feet:", meters * feet_in_meter)
print("Converted to inches:", meters * inches_in_meter)
print("Converted to miles:", meters / meters_in_mile)
input()
```

Comment: I guess 0.000621371 is the conversion for 1mt to mile

Comment: So why multiply meters with `ft_in_yard`? You got your yards and meters mixed up.

Comment: You are multiplying meters by 'feet in yards', not 'feet in meters'.

Comment: In other words, don't you need to convert those meters to yards first?

Comment: Looks like the math is wrong... Check your units, you're multiplying meters by ft/yard, when you should multiply meters by feet/meter.

Comment: Okay makes sense i was doing it backwards. I was trying to go off a few examples I found in the book using different subjects.

Comment: `meters * ft_in_yard` ---  "meters" does not appear in "feet in yard"; that should be a huge clue that these two variables don't work together.

Comment: made some changes and makes more sense now

Comment: `meters_in_foot` should be called `feet_in_meter`.  This is the opposite of my previous comment --- this time, your calculation is correct, but the names are wrong.  You (correctly) divide `meters` by `meters_in_mile`, but you _multiply_ `meters` by `meters_in_foot`...  That just screams "error".  (As it happens, the error is the name, not the operator.)

Comment: Im so dumb. Im sorry. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ft_in_yard`, but we're using meters, so you should instead do:

```
meter_in_foot = 3.28084
print("Converted to feet", meters * meter_in_foot)
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense, I was going off a table in the book using something different and threw me off.